# Java DB Derby driver loading

Tags: java, database, loading, derby

I'm wondering if I have to load the derby driver everytime I want to initiate a connection, using the Class.forName("...") function. Could I just load this in the main function of my program and it would stay into ram until the program exits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can load `JDBC` driver into any method/class before its use. You may also use [static block](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) to load database driver.

```
public class Test
{
   static
    {
       //load driver here
    }
}
```

Comment: My question is: is it required? I'm pretty sure loading it will slow the execution...

Comment: You have to load it only `once`, a static block will get you there. A better way is to use `DriverManager` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Embedded Derby** [here are the instructions on how to acquire a Database connection](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html).

Note you should only load the `Driver` once, this can be in a `static` block of your main method, or in a `JNDI` lookup if you are using an application server, which is a completely different story. Either way you can reuse it for all your connections.

Using the Network version [is a completely different story](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html). This is the only way to get around the **single JVM** restriction of Embedded mode.